# By jquery, select table row with radio button value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html-table

I am populating a Table with data from Database. Table row has a radio button. Using jquery how to check which radio of a row is checked? then how to read the columns values of that row?

Here is the table population code.

```
<table id="wo_table" class="table table-striped responsive-utilities table-hover jambo_table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="headings">
            <th>
                <input type="checkbox" id="selectOne" class="flat">
            </th>
            <th class="column-title">WO Id </th>
            <th class="column-title">Create Date </th>
            <th class="column-title">Buyer </th>
            <th class="column-title">Style </th>
            <th class="column-title">Quantity </th>
            <th class="column-title">GG </th>
            <th class="column-title">Status </th>
            <th class="column-title">Remarks </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <?php
        $queryString="SELECT * FROM win_work_order";
        fetchWOList($queryString);
            function fetchWOList($queryString){
                include 'ConnectionToDatabase.php';
                $result=mysql_query($queryString);

                while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    echo
                        '<tr class="even pointer">
                            <td class="a-center ">
                                <input type="radio" class="flat" name="table_records"    value=' .$test['WO_ID']. '></td>
                            <td class=" ">' .$test['WO_ID']. '</td>
                            <td class=" ">' .$test['WO_CREATE_DATE']. '</td>
                            <td class=" ">' .$test['BUYER_NAME']. '</td>
                            <td class=" ">' .$test['STYLE_NAME']. '</td>
                            <td class=" ">' .$test['WO_QTY']. '</td>
                            <td class=" ">' .$test['CURRENCY_QTY_GG']. '</td>
                            <td class=" ">' .$test['WO_STATUS']. '</td>
                            <td class=" ">' .$test['WO_REMARKS']. '</td>';

                    echo "</tr>";
                }

                mysql_close($conn);

            }

        ?>

    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/)

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#wo_table input:radio:checked').val()` will give you the ID, or `undefined` if nothing's checked. Don't read the data from the HTML, use the ID you got, validate its format, then fetch the row with that ID to do something with its data.